# Special characters in ANSII through VBA

Tags: vba, excel, encoding

I've implemented a vba script which creates folders, files, and put description in files for each row. 
Problem is serbian latin letters such as "š,đ,č,ć,ž". Files must be recorded in ANSII .txt file beacause of one another program..
The more awkward is that the first file is ok in .txt (ANSII encoding) and it keeps čćšđš letters, but the others are not ok..

Maybe I need to change keyboard settings in Control Panel?

On this link I've uploaded test file:[File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7t6k37dlgzcu08t/Book1.xlsx?dl=0)

Please run this easy code, and please give me any feedback.
Thanks!

```
Sub files()
Dim iRow As Long
Dim iFile As Integer
Dim sPath As String
Dim sFile As String


For iRow = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    iFile = FreeFile
    With Rows(iRow)
        sPath = "E:\" & .Range("B1").Value & "\"
        If Len(Dir(sPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir sPath
        sFile = .Range("D1").Value & ".txt"
        Open sPath & sFile For Output As #iFile
        Print #iFile, .Range("E1").Value
        Close #iFile
    End With
Next iRow
End Sub
```

P.S. For list of these characters in unicode I want to be in ASCII:

- U+0106  Ć   0xC4 0x86   \304\206    Ć
- U+0107 ć   0xC4 0x87   \304\207    ć
- U+010C Č   0xC4 0x8C   \304\214    Č
- U+010D č   0xC4 0x8D   \304\215    č
- U+0110 Đ   0xC4 0x90   \304\220    Đ
- U+0111 đ   0xC4 0x91   \304\221    đ
- U+0160 Š   0xC5 0xA0   \305\240    Š
- U+0161 š   0xC5 0xA1   \305\241    š
- U+017D Ž   0xC5 0xBD   \305\275    Ž
- U+017E ž   0xC5 0xBE   \305\276    ž

Comment: If this is working this should be moved to code review

Comment: @Vogel612 missed that. My bad - need my morning coffee yet.

Comment: I have edited the code and added the screenshot as well. Empty the output folder and try the code code that i gave below. You may have to refresh the page...

Answer (score 1):

This is what I tried and it works...

```
Sub files()
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim sPath As String, sFile As String
    Dim fs As Object

    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    For iRow = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
        sPath = "E:\" & Range("B1").Value & "\"

        If Len(Dir(sPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir sPath

        sFile = Range("D" & iRow).Value & ".txt"

        With fs
            With .CreateTextFile(sPath & sFile, , True)
                .Write Range("E" & iRow).Value
                .Close
            End With
        End With
    Next iRow
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your version of the code. It is a much better. Code is a minor issue here, Ive put it just for you to see that text in txt ANSII files.. Why for some cells code writes those specific letters with hooks ćčšđ, for others partially, and for thirds ones it dont? Thanks for the code again!

Comment: Like I said the code didn't work for only one row (6th). For the rest it worked

Comment: nope, only for the second row it prints ok, for the others I have loss of characters...

Comment: Thanks mate! You saved me! Great!

Comment: Just I need to re-arrange folders, when I will differnet names in B column.. :)

Comment: Siddharth Rout, files that program creates are in Unicode format, I need them in ANSII..so I still have problem.. tnx anyway!

Comment: how would you like the output to be? May I see a screenshot?

Comment: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6hcwb82c4rl8hc1/ansii.png?dl=0) It's a must to be as ANSI formated. On my server at the office, I can with ease create an ansi document with these "special" characters, but on my machine, it keeps me warning about, if I want to save in ANSI, I will loose some of data.. Is the screenshot ok? do you want something more? tnx!